# C# Unity how to resolve a class which already has got injections using factory method

Tags: c#-4.0, unity-container

I have two implementation of an interface. Eg; I have an interface named IWriter. And two implementation such as FileWriter (which writes to a folder) and FTPWriter which uploads file to FTP. I would like to resolve based on a config setting. so need to use a factory method. Both FileWriter and FTPWriter has got some interfaces injected in their constructors. So how do i resolve this?

```
public interface IWriter{ void Write();}
public class FileWriter : IWriter{
    public FileWriter(IInterface interface1, IInterface 2)
    {

    }
}

public class FTPWriter : IWriter{
    public FTPWriter(IInterface interface1, IInterface 2)
    {

    }
}

public static Factory
{
    public IWriter GetWriter(string mode)
    {
        if(mode=="1")
            return new FileWriter();//But i need the object to the interface1, interface2 injected
        else
            return new FTPWriter(); //But i need the object to the interface1, interface2 injected

    }
}

public class MainService : IMainService{
     public MainClass(IOtherInterface other, IWriter writer){

     }
}
```

My unity config:

```
container.RegisterType<IMainService, MainService >();
```

Thanks